# How an optional property can be ignored when using jackson to convert Java object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson 1.9.2(org.codehaus.jackson) to convent from Java object to matching JSON construct. Here is my java object:

```
Class ColorLight {
    String type;
    boolean isOn;
    String value;

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean getIsOn(){
        return isOn;
    }

    public setIsOn(boolean isOn) {
        this.isOn = isOn;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

If I did the following conversion, I'd get the result I want.

```
ColorLight light = new ColorLight();
light.setType("red");
light.setIsOn("true");
light.setValue("255");
objectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString();
```

jsonString would be like:

```
{"type":"red","isOn":"true", "value":"255"}
```

But sometimes I don't have the value of isOn property

```
ColorLight light = new ColorLight();
light.setType("red");
light.setValue("255");
```

But the jsonString is still like:

```
{"type":"red","isOn":"false", "value":"255"}
```

Where "isOn:false" is default value of Java boolean type which I don't want it be there.
How can I remove the isOn property in the final json construct like this?

```
{"type":"red","value":"255"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To skip the value if it's not present:

- Use `Boolean` instead of the `boolean` primitive (`boolean` values are always set to `true` or `false`).
- Configure Jackson not to serialize nulls by using `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` or `@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)`, depending on the version.

Answer (score 7):

You can mark your class with the `@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)` in 1.x annotation that indicates that only properties that have values that differ from default settings (meaning values they have when Bean is constructed with its no-arguments constructor) are to be included.

The `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)` annotation is used for version 2.x.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonInclusion {

    @JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT)
    public static class ColorLight {
        public String type;
        public boolean isOn;

        public ColorLight() {
        }

        public ColorLight(String type, boolean isOn) {
            this.type = type;
            this.isOn = isOn;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ColorLight light = new ColorLight("value", false);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(light));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"type":"value"}
```