# Spring Rest docs ignore request body fields in documentation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I have the followin situation:

My Endpoint consumes an Object A that results in the backend depending on the requesting user to Object B or C. So the problem is, that Object A has all the fields of Object B and C. As a result I want to ignore request fields for a specific user group because they are always null and are irgnored in the backend.

Is there a way to set a .ignore option for request fields so I can provide the example JSON request body when using the http-request.snippet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How an optional property can be ignored when using jackson to convert Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622635/how-an-optional-property-can-be-ignored-when-using-jackson-to-convert-java-objec)

Comment: I can‘t try it right now but I thought Rest-docs documents the receiving object not the Object sent in the request. So the receiving objects field will still be null?